# Remote debugging showing android device but not inspect option samsung tab gt-p5100

Tags: android, cordova, remote-debugging, inspect

Hi I'am working on phonegap. I have two devices Samsung S3 (android 4.4) and Samsung tab GT-PT5100(android 4.2) 
my problem is when I connect S3 my device shows and I can inspect my app
but when I try to connect Samsung tab I can view my device but there is no option for inspect

can anyone help?

Comment: i have enabled usb-debugging and i have enabled in chromer browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quote from [Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) :

> **To begin remote debugging, you will need:**
>
> For Android apps: Android 4.4+ and a WebView configured for debugging.

So for cordova application Android 4.4+ is required.

Comment: any other options for remote debugging on samasung tab

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap) , it provide all options in cordova for remote debugging.

Comment: check [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) , i have heard good things about it but have not tried yet.